# Suggestions for automating R script?

Tags: r, shell, automation, r-markdown, data-analysis

I'm currently working on a data analysis project requiring two packages only available in R, and I already have a general script written for this. I want to automate this as much as possible for the org I am working for, so that they can run it without opening R and then receive the output figures/tables (either as an html/pdf or each output saved individually to a directory) by providing one or a couple arguments. They probably would only be running this a few times a year, but the only thing changing each time is an ID# for the data retrieval and perhaps some time arguments.

I work on a Mac, so naturally I considered just writing the script to run with a one-liner from the command line with a couple of args so they can alter the fields of interest. One of the main difficulties I have is that everyone else in the org uses Windows computers so I'm not sure how well that would transfer or if there was a way to make it agnostic. Other thoughts include just using R Markdown and having them manually change the main argument, or even working with Shiny to have the figures be generated after they type in the argument ID# and then they could just a few other parameters with drop downs (but I have never used Shiny before, so it would require a bit of research on my part).

Any suggestions at all for automating this type of script in a way that would work on most computers with minimal adjustments? I have been searching but most results seem to pull up replies with TaskScheduler, which isn't really what I am looking for yet. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: launchd or cron is what you're actually wanting on MacOS. TaskScheduler is more Windows. If you're running local automated tasks without manually starting a script, these options are what you are looking for.

Comment: _"few times a year"_ and _"each time is an ID# for the data"_ to me does not at all suggest "scheduling", whether with cron, launchd, or task scheduler. To me it suggests `shiny` or `plumber`. If you have a budget (or have other things published in R or python), I'd suggest Posit Connect (commercial license only) or Shiny Server (both commercial and open-source/free licenses), but those are a bit of an admin overhead and learning curve if you only need it a few times.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something like Shiny would make more sense, although you're right that there is certainly a learning curve. There are hundreds of ID#s that exist for this data source (and it's all open source data), so it seems like shiny would be worth it for their exploratory data analysis purposes. Do you have any recs on learning Shiny? I know Wickham has his book, but happy to take any other suggestions!